# fluent validation custom message depending on another property

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have this Entity

```
 public class Entity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RequestTypeId { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentTypeId { get; set; }
        ...

    }
```

I want to display a different error message on `DepartmentTypeID` depending on the `RequestTypeId`

So for example:

```
When(m => m.RequestyTypeId == 1,
 () => {
    RuleFor(m => m.DepartmentTypeID).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Custom Message 1");
});

When(m => m.RequestyTypeId == 2,
     () => {
        RuleFor(m => m.DepartmentTypeID).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Custom Message 2");
});
```

This is not working... Am I doing something wrong? How do i handle cases like this?

Comment: The code looks correct. Are you only seeing one error or not seeing either?

Comment: I am seen the default .net MVC error -> "'Department Type I D' can't not be empty" or something like that. I am not see the Custom Message. If I move the RuleFor outside the when it works fine. If i add one RuleFor in either When, the new RuleFor work but  the DepartmentTypeID ruleFor  don't work. If that make sense... It is kinda weird.

Comment: It might be MVC related. I can see the correct behavior in a Console app using what you have entered. What if you try using `GreaterThan` like this instead; it is functionally the same as `NotEmpty` - `RuleFor(m => m.DepartmentTypeID).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Custom Message 1");`